# Pasting image with Alpha transpency

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, transparency, alpha

I have a piece of code that takes a string and constructs a graffiti-like image from that string. The letters are all individual .PNG images that are read in and pasted onto a new, longer image. My problem is that while the background alpha channel is in fact preserved, where the letters overlap it is not. Please see image.

How can I paste these letters overlapping while preserving alpha channel? It seems that both alpha_composite and blend functions need identical images to work.

It should be noted that I can do this either in Python or C++, I just used python now because it seemed very fast and easy.

IMAGE of problem

[image]

One original letter

[image]

EDIT: Here is the code. For sure there must be better ways to do this.

```
import sys
from PIL import Image


def openLetters(letters):

    files = {
        'A': 'A-rens.png',
        'B': 'B-rens.png',
        'C': 'C-rens.png',
        'D': 'D-rens.png',
        'E': 'E-rens.png',
        'F': 'F-rens.png',
        'G': 'G-rens.png',
        'H': 'H-rens.png',
        'I': 'I-rens.png',
        'J': 'J-rens.png',
        'K': 'K-rens.png',
        'L': 'L-rens.png',
        'M': 'M-rens.png',
        'N': 'N-rens.png',
        'O': 'O-rens.png',
        'P': 'P-rens.png',
        'Q': 'Q-rens.png',
        'R': 'R-rens.png',
        'S': 'S-rens.png',
        'T': 'T-rens.png',
        'U': 'U-rens.png',
        'V': 'V-rens.png',
        'W': 'W-rens.png',
        'X': 'X-rens.png',
        'Y': 'Y-rens.png',
        'Z': 'Z-rens.png',
    }



    images = []
    for letter in letters:
        images.append(Image.open(files[letter]))
        print "Opened:" + files[letter]


    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

    totalWidth = sum(widths)
    maxHeight = max(heights)

    newImage = Image.new('RGBA', (totalWidth, maxHeight))

    x_offset = 0

    for im in images:
        newImage.paste(im, (x_offset, 0), mask=0)
        x_offset += im.size[0] - 200

    newImage.save(letters + ".png")


openLetters("ANDERS")
```

Comment: Please share some of the images of the individual letters and also your code.

Comment: According to your picture the single letter pings seem to lack transparency and would required some postprocessing to get it. Switching to C++ is unlikely to help here.

Comment: Yep, it looks like you just need to treat each letter like a seperate PNG image insofar as adding an alpha layer. Then they should paste ok. Easiest done in python. Holler and I'll give you the python piece to simply add/mod the alpha layer on a png for exactly this purpose.

Comment: I have edited the post and included the code I use.

Comment: David Kierans: I would love to see the python code, but how can I message you? There is no PM function here on this site right?

Comment: Please provide separate images of a few letters.

Comment: Mark: I added a letter :)

Comment: Steady on - don't give me too many to play with! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as it sounds, you just want the easiest way, I would suggest **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. Just in Terminal or at Command Prompt:

```
magick a.png a.png a.png +smush -140  result.png
```

[image]

Change from `+smush` to `-smush` to append vertically. Increase the 140 to overlap more, or decrease it to overlap less.

---

If your **ImageMagick** version is older than v7, replace `magick` in my command with `convert`.

---

As you didn't give me enough letters to play with, you'll have to make do with this for your Python version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PIL import Image


w = 3000
h = 1490

newImage = Image.new('RGBA', (w, h))
myMiserableA = Image.open('a.png').convert('RGBA')

x_offset = 0

for im in range(3):
    newImage.paste(myMiserableA, (x_offset, 0), mask=myMiserableA)
    x_offset += 1000

newImage.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for! A big thank you!

Comment: `@Hyperkub`. Just a suggestion since you are a relatively new user on this forum. It is generally polite to up vote an answer that has helped you.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that is true. I had forgot about the low score issue and did not recall it applied to voting. I have upvoted your post to help in that regard.